# css repeating background scroll bar too long

Tags: css

I have a simple repeating background image in my css that is 211 x 211 pixels and on all my webpages there is a scrollbar on the right of the page that goes way beyond the content of the page (like 2-3 times as long) that just shows the background image.  I feel like I'm missing something really simple.

This is my code

```
body {
    background-image:url(CSS_Images/white_sand.png);
    background-repeat:repeat;
    height:100%;

}
```

Comment: Your problem isn't caused by that background statement. Post more code or a demo.

Comment: Post the HTML of your site, sounds like an HTML issue, NOT CSS.

Comment: I found the answer to my question. Thanks @Pete for recommending the Chrome dom inspector. I had a div that I made a huge height on (9000px!). I changed the height to 100% and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what the question is but if it's that your background image doesn't continue if the page is too long:

use `min-height` instead of `height` - if your page is longer than the viewport it will stop at 100% of the viewport (not 100% of the document)

If it is that your page is just too long, you may want to get a dom inspector and inspect the space, it will usually tell you what is causing the space to be created (chrome has a built in dom inspector)

Comment: I found the answer to my question.  Thanks @Pete for recommending the Chrome dom inspector.  I had a div that I made a huge height on (9000px!).  I changed the height to 100% and it solved the problem.